# SSRS IIF expression with multiple criteria

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to default this fields date value based on multiple criteria.

I have a field for 'Program_Status' which can either be 'active' or 'inactive' or 'complete'
I have a field for 'Program_Ended_On' which is my field I am trying to populate.

Criteria:
If field 'Program_Status' is <>'Active' 
and the field 'Program_Ended_On' is within 30 days past up till today, then I want to display the 'End Date'.

I have tried several ways with errors.
=IIF(
Fields!Program_Status.Value <>"Active", Dateadd("m",-1,today()),Fields!Program_Ended_On.Value)

Any thoughts?
Thank you

Comment: You can improve the readability of your question by following these easy code formatting tips: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code. 
If Program_status is not equal to Active and if Program_Ended_On is within 1 month of today then the expression will give Program_Ended_On value else it will give 0 as output. You can modify this expression as per your requirement

```
=IIF(Fields!Program_Status.Value<>"Active" AND Fields!Program_Ended_On.Value  >= DATEADD("m",-1,Today()),Fields!Program_Ended_On.Value,0)
```

Comment: Hi @sramsey222 , Please mark it as answer if it works.